# Real time updates through Cramp(Ruby) and SSE(HTML5)

Tags: ruby, html, ruby-on-rails-3, server-sent-events, cramp

I have prepared a sample application to get updates from server in real time using [Cramp(Ruby)](http://cramp.in/) and [SSE(HTML5)](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/eventsource/basics/).

I am getting following errors while accessing the html through `http://localhost/sse_time.html`

```
Errors:
Chrome:
  Uncaught Error: SECURITY_ERR: DOM Exception 18 sse_time.html:9
  Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'key-preview' of undefined 

Firefox:
  Error: The character encoding of the HTML document was not declared. The document will render with garbled text in some browser configurations if the document contains characters from outside the US-ASCII range. The character encoding of the page must to be declared in the document or in the transfer protocol.
Line: 0

  Error: The connection to http://localhost:3000/time was interrupted while the page was loading.
  Line: 9
```

**sse_time.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<h1>Getting server updates</h1>
<div id="result"></div>
<script>
  if (!!window.EventSource) {

    var source = new EventSource('http://localhost:3000/time');

    source.addEventListener('message', function(e) {
      console.log(e.data);
    }, false);

    source.addEventListener('open', function(e) {
      // Connection was opened.
      console.log('Connection was opened.');
    }, false);

    source.addEventListener('error', function(e) {
      if (e.readyState == EventSource.CLOSED) {
        // Connection was closed.
        console.log('Connection was closed.');
      }
    }, false);

  } else {
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML="Sorry, your browser does not support server-sent events...";
  }
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

**app/actions/time_action.rb**

```
class TimeAction < Cramp::Action
  self.transport = :sse

  periodic_timer :send_latest_time, every: 5

  def send_latest_time
    render "Current time : #{Time.now}"
  end
end
```

where `line 9` is `var source = new EventSource('http://localhost:3000/time');`

If I hit `http://localhost:3000/time` in chrome, it shows time after each 5 seconds without any errors.

However with PHP code it works fine replacing URI `http://localhost:3000/time` with `stream.php` in `sse_time.html`

**stream.php**

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/event-stream');
header('Cache-Control: no-cache'); // recommended to prevent caching of event data.

/**
 * Constructs the SSE data format and flushes that data to the client.
 *
 * @param string $id Timestamp/id of this connection.
 * @param string $msg Line of text that should be transmitted.
 */
function sendMsg($id, $msg) {
  echo "id: $id" . PHP_EOL;
  echo "data: $msg" . PHP_EOL;
  echo PHP_EOL;
  ob_flush();
  flush();
}

$serverTime = time();

sendMsg($serverTime, 'server time: ' . date("h:i:s", time()));
```

Here `stream.php` and `sse_time.html` resides at same locaation.

Would anyone please guide me to fix this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Referring to [CASE STUDY: REAL-TIME UPDATES IN STREAM CONGRESS](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/casestudies/sunlight_streamcongress/)

> A significant issue to keep in mind with EventSource is that cross-domain connections are not allowed. This means that the Cramp app must be served from the same streamcongress.com domain as the main Rails app.

I realize the html page also needs to be part of the cramp application(though there is alternative). So I made following changes and it worked.

Modified `app/actions/home_action.rb` based on [Cramp chat using Redis Pub/Sub + WebSockets](https://github.com/lifo/cramp-pub-sub-chat-demo)

```
class HomeAction < Cramp::Action
  @@template = ERB.new(File.read(PocRailsCramp::Application.root('app/views/index.html.erb')))

  def start
    render @@template.result(binding)
    finish
  end
end
```

and the content of `app/views/index.html.erb` is same as the content of `sse_time.html` in the the question itself.

Now hitting `http://localhost:3000` started showing server time in each 5 seconds on browser console.

Comment: CORS connections is supported by Opera and Firefox; also you can use js version of EventSource with CORS supported